# how to prevent emacs org from export email address to link

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In emacs org mode :

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :eval no                                                                                                                                  
git commit --amend --author 'New Author Name <email@address.com>'                                                                                        
#+END_SRC
```

will export to :

```
<pre class="src src-sh">
      git commit --amend --author <span style="color: #ffff00;">"New Author Name <a href="mailto:email%40address.com">&lt;email@address.com&gt;</a>"</span>
</pre>
```

where email address contains, not literal as expected :

```
<pre class="src src-sh">
      git commit --amend --author <span style="color: #ffff00;">"New Author Name &lt;email@address.com&gt;"</span>
</pre>
```

is there some export arguments for ?

very thank your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any applicable export options, but another approach is to experiment with [filtering](http://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-export-reference.html#filter-system) the export (Org 8.0.5):

```
(require 'ox)

(defun keith/remove-a-href (string backend info)
  "remove <a href..."
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
   (replace-regexp-in-string "<a href.*?>" "" string)))

(defun keith/remove-a-close-tag (string backend info)
  "remove </a>"
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
   (replace-regexp-in-string "</a>" "" string)))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-final-output-functions
             'keith/remove-a-href)
(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-final-output-functions
             'keith/remove-a-close-tag)
```

Result of `org-export-html-to-html` on your example, before filtering:

```
<pre class="src src-sh">
      git commit --amend --author <span style="color: #95e454;">'New Author Name &lt;<a href="mailto:email&#64;address.com">email&#64;address.com</a>&gt;'</span>
</pre>
```

And after filtering:

```
<pre class="src src-sh">
      git commit --amend --author <span style="color: #95e454;">'New Author Name &lt;email&#64;address.com&gt;'</span>
</pre>
```